# SQL - Select Fields of the Max ID

Tags: sql, mysql

The last InvoiceID, and corresponding fields needs to be selected.  The entire sql contains several inner joins.

```
SELECT max(InvoiceID), 
       InvoiceEndDate 
  FROM Invoices 
 WHERE TransactionOrderItemID = '000831'
```

Right now, I am getting the InvoiceID, and have to fetch the InvoiceEndDate again.

Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT InvoiceID, InvoiceEndDate 
FROM Invoices 
WHERE TransactionOrderItemID='000831'
ORDER BY InvoiceID DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Glad I saw that.  If that works, it's way easier than the way I was going to suggest...

Comment: OP says MySQL, so LIMIT 1 would be needed after the order by instead of TOP 1 before the select list.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT InvoiceID, InvoiceEndDate 
FROM Invoices INV
WHERE TransactionOrderItemID='000831'
  AND INV.InvoiceID = (SELECT MAX(SUB.InvoiceID)
    FROM Invoices SUB WHERE SUB.TransactionOrderItemID='000831');
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Including an Aggregated Column's Related Values](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/including-an-aggregated-column-s-related) which has several ways to accomplish this

Comment: Okay didn't know it was MySQL...I saw TOP in the first answer and assumed it was SQl Server